# Why regex match is not what I expect?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I try to implement following code, but it's prints out not what I expect

```
import re

def regex_search(txt):
    lst = re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}\.){3}', txt)
    return lst

print(regex_search("123.45.67.89"))
```

It prints out ['67.'] when I expect ['123.', '45.', '67.']. Where I am wrong? Help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your actual expected output?  Why do you not want to also the `89` final component of the IP address?  Why do you want the periods to be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the quantifer `{3}` and also get rid of extra grouping and write this code,

```
import re

def regex_search(txt):
    lst = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.', txt)
    return lst

print(regex_search("123.45.67.89"))
```

Prints your expected output,

```
['123.', '45.', '67.']
```

Also, as you were using this `(\d{1,3}\.){3}`, then it will match exactly three of this `\d{1,3}\.` repeatedly three times which would be `123.45.67.` as whole match but will group1 will capture only the last match which is `67.` in your case and hence prints only that value in list.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was wrong from the beginning. Now I don't understand why it is not printing smt like `['123.45.67.']` with this `(\d{1,3}\.){3}`. And instead only match `['67.']`

Comment: @Zarkos: Your regex was a little not correct. Regex is a great tool and quite useful at times. I'll suggest you to get familiar with its basics at least. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) which contains good info on basic regex stuff and also has good references to really useful websites.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is useful but not for every situation and it is slower than built-in methods. The tutorial that I learned regex from said so too. I am just trying to use it after I thought I learnt some basic stuff about it but I am stuck with this quantifier and don't understand why it is not working as I expect it to, and matches only '67.'

Comment: @Zarkos: Regex is like a double edged sword. You need to know where to apply and where not else it may backfire :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to even use regex here:

```
input = "123.45.67.89"
parts = input.split(".")
parts = [s + "." for s in parts]
parts = parts[:-1]
print(parts)

['123.', '45.', '67.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your regex slightly and now it should work.

```
import re

def regex_search(txt):
    lst = re.findall(r'(\d{1,3}\.)', txt)
    return lst

print(regex_search("123.45.67.89"))
```

The output will now be.

```
['123.', '45.', '67.']
```

You can also do it without regex, splitting on `.` and ignoring last element

```
import re

def regex_search(txt):
    items = txt.split('.')[:-1]
    return [item+'.' for item in items]

print(regex_search("123.45.67.89"))
```

The output will be

```
['123.', '45.', '67.']
```